# Adding population to SVG map with javascript

Tags: jquery, arrays, svg

I have implemented a clickable interactive SVG map, and so far I've been able to implement the name of each country onto the clickable elements of the SVG with the following if else statements;

```
map.getLayer('world_border').style('fill', function(data) {
    if (data.iso == "US")
        return "#C2BFBD";
    else if (data.iso == "CANADA")
        return "#C2BFBD";
    else if (data.iso == "GREAK BRITAIN")
        return "#C2BFBD";
    else if (data.iso == "JAPAN")
        return "#C2BFBD";
    else if (data.iso == "KR")
        return "#C2BFBD";
    else if (data.iso == "DENMARK")
        return "#C2BFBD";
    else if (data.iso == "FRANCE")
        return "#C2BFBD";
    else if (data.iso == "CANADA")
        return "#C2BFBD";
    else if (data.iso == "ITALY")
        return "#C2BFBD";
    else if (data.iso == "AUSTRALIA")
        return "#C2BFBD";
    else
        return "#C2BFBD";
});
```

However, at the minute the population is is static number for each country. How can I implement the different populations for the different countries the same way as the countries?

[Here](http://itssjp.co.uk/map/) is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple different options.  First, you can write out a JSON structure with the country-population data as key-value pairs.  This could be done as

```
var popData = {
  'usa' : 740958,
  'gb' : 209834,
  ...
  ...
};
```

Or you can implement a jQuery Ajax call to query a database with the values.  It really depends on how static your data is and the ease of altering it.  I personally vastly prefer the Ajax data call, and you can do this by modifying your `click` handler

```
map.getLayer('world_border').on('click', function(data, path, event) {

  $.post({
    url : "/getPopData",
    data : "data" : data.iso,
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(result){
      //modify the country and population span elements from the data results
    }
  });
}
```